# Magento 2.2 : Upgrade customer_eav_attribute table 2.1 to 2.2

Tags: magento2, database, attributes, upgrade

After updating Magento 2.1 to Magento 2.2 I get the following error when saving a client.

[image]

I have seen that in the customer_eav_attribute table the data has not been updated correctly to the new version.

For exemple, I have:

> a:2:{s:15:"max_text_length";i:255;s:15:"min_text_length";i:1;}

And in version 2.2 it is necessary to have:

> {"max_text_length":255,"min_text_length":1}

How to update this table? without reinstall Magento 2.2

Answer (score 1):

you have to convert and update in your database. You can resolve it in **file /vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php** by using this query:

```
    public function unserialize($string)
{
    $result = json_decode($string, true);
    if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        $result = @$this->unserialize($string);
        if($result){
            return $result;
        }
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Unable to unserialize value. Error: " . json_last_error_msg());
    }
    return $result;
}
```